# ActiveRecord join with Array of IDs

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following command is useful in pulling out all Styles with a certain feature:

```
Style.joins(:style_features).where('style_features.feature_id= ?', 1)
```

Is it possible to do the same thing, but for a series of features? As in:

```
Style.joins(:style_features).where('style_features.feature_id= ?', [1, 2, 3])
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
Style.joins(:style_features).where(style_features: { feature_id: [1, 2, 3] })
```

This query will let Rails deal with the SQL query depending on the DataBase Adapter you defined.

Answer (score 1):

you can try with `Style.joins(:style_features).where('style_features.feature_id in (?)', [1, 2, 3])`

MrYoshiji Answer is better then me if looking at rails way